# symfony2 createAction with OneToMany

Tags: symfony, entity, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have 2 entities. Entity Category with 2 columns: `id, caName`. Entity Service with 4 columns: `id, seName, sePrice, caId`. Column `caId` in the Service are contain `id` of Category.

My goal is making a createAction, editAction and deleteAction for the Service. I have no problem with editAction and deleteAction. However, my createAction returns 500 (Internal Server Error).

Log:

Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Entity\Service::setCaId() must be an instance of AppBundle\Entity\Category, integer given, called in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/symfony_luxurysalon/src/AppBundle/Controller/ServiceController.php on line 67 and defined

Category entity:

```
class Category
{
  /**
   * @var int
   *
   * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
   * @ORM\OneToMany(
   *   targetEntity="Service",
   *   mappedBy="caId"
   * )
   */
  private $id;

  ...

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->id = new ArrayCollection();
  }

  /**
  * Get id
  *
  * @return Service
  */
  public function getId()
  {
     return $this->id;
  }

  ...
}
```

Service entity:

```
class Service
{
   ...

  /**
  * @var int
  *
  * @ORM\Column(name="ca_id", type="integer", length=2)
  * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="id", cascade={"persist","remove"})
  * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")
  */
  private $caId;

  ...

  /**
  * Set caId
  *
  * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Category $caId
  *
  * @return Service
  */
  public function setCaId(\AppBundle\Entity\Category $caId = null)
  {
      $this->caId = $caId;
      return $this;
  }

  /**
  * Get caId
  *
  * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Category
  */
  public function getCaId()
  {
    return $this->caId;
  }
}
```

Controller:

```
$entity = new Service();
$entity
  ->setSeName("test")
  ->setSePrice("200");
  ->setCaId("2");

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($entity);
$em->flush();
```

Comment: Please post the log for this request. Without it one could only guess what the real issue is (especially given that your code even isn't complete).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass a `Category` instance instead of an id to the `setCaId()` method (btw. the name is misleading if you do not expect an id to be passed, something like `setCategory()` would be more appropriate). So you will have to first look up the category with id 2 from the repository and then pass this category to the method:

```
$doctrine = $this->getDoctrine();

$category = $doctrine->getRepository('AppBundle:Category')->find(2);

$service = new Service();
$service->setCaId($category);

$em = $doctrine->getManager();
$em->persist($service);
$em->flush();
```

You may want to add some logic dealing with the case that `find()` does not return a result (e.g. when no category with id 2 does exist).

Comment: Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class AppBundle\Entity\Category could not be converted to string

Comment: I tried $service->setCaId($category->getId()). It returns me a same error as above.

Comment: "Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class AppBundle\Entity\Category could not be converted to string " Can you show the complete stack trace for this error?

Comment: Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException: "An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO service (se_name, se_price, se_note, ca_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["abc", "200", " ", {}]: Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class AppBundle\Entity\Category could not be converted to string" at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/store/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/DBALException.php line 119

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that the mapping type of your `$caId` property is `integer`. You should take a look into how to model associations between entities in Doctrine: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html